# iptables string match does not work whe the --to option is < 52

Tags: security, iptables, firewall, bash

when I enter iptables rule which match string and the `--to` option is `>= 52`

example

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -m string --string anypattern --algo bm --to 100 -j DROP
```

The above works properly and block ip packets which contains "anypattern" string.

Now if I change the `--to` to a value `< 52` then it will not work

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -m string --string anypattern --algo bm --to 50 -j DROP
```

And the ip packets will not be blocked!

Am I missing something ? or this is an iptables issue ?

**Example:**

```
linux:~$ sudo iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -m string --algo bm --string 7oula --to 52 -j DROP
linux:~$ echo 7oulaaaaaaaaaaa | nc  212.227.247.109 80
^C  #<---- Blocked here ==> Good
linux:~$ sudo iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -m string --algo bm --string coula --to 51 -j DROP
linux:~$ echo coulaaaaaaaaaaa | nc  212.227.247.109 80
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 26 Jan 2020 15:35:55 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 150
Connection: close

<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: From the doc: `--to offset`: *Set the offset from which it starts looking for any matching. If not passed, default is the packet size*. How did you determine that value of 52 ? Your packets must be bigger than that due to the overhead.

Answer (score 2):

The `--to` option gives you the **maximal** offset at which your string can start. The offset is relative to the start of the IP packet. If you add up:

- **20** bytes for the IP header,
- **20** bytes for the TCP header,
- **12** bytes for some TCP options

you'll end up with 52 bytes. So the start of the TCP payload is at offset 52, anything less than that will match just the TCP/IP headers.

Remark that the TCP options do not have a fixed length. The number 12 was obtained experimentally through **tcpdump**, but every system can send a different number of options.

Comment: Up to another 40 bytes for IPv4 header options. Theoretically, up to 60 bytes for IPv4 header, and up to 60 bytes for TCP header.

Comment: There is also, the problem of fragmented packets, where only the first fragment contains the TCP header, and the subsequent fragments do not.

Comment: @RonMaupin, thanks for the remarks. Basically the OP should not use the `--to` option, maybe he can use the `--from 40` option, but the best solution is not to filter at this level and let the web server do the filtering.